# finding a element within a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

So I'm trying to get my count to add 1 whenever it sees the yea in the tuple. my issue is it still returns 0. Should I use a for loop to go through each item?

```
year = input ("enter a year")
count = 0 

t = (("Steve"), ("Carell"), (16, "August", 1962), 
            "Actor", ("Concord", "Massachusetts"))

if year in t:
     count += 1

print(count) 
print (t) #just a check
```

expected results 
input: 1962
output: 1

Comment: What o/p you expect for input 1962 if you have tuple as `t = (("Steve",), ("Carell",), (16, "August", 1962),
            "1962", 1962 ("Concord", "Massachusetts"))`?

Comment: its just an example I'm writing a bigger code which involved a large tuple and I'm just trying to count  how many times a date occurs @hygull

Comment: That is ok. I just want to know if you will have your year as an integer or it will be a string also. What are possible data structures where I can search for year.

Comment: it doesn't matter in the tuple they are integers. so whatever makes me helps me count. but i get a type error if i do like int(year) in t @hygull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As t is a tuple of tuples you need to loop through each tuple and find the occurrences of the year in that tuple. It can also be possible to have year 2 times in the same tuple, so you need to loop through every element in the inner tuple.
The tuple contains integer as well as strings so we cannot compare a string with integer so convert the element to string before you compare with a year

```
year = input ("enter a year")
count = 0 
t = (("Steve"), ("Carell"), (16, "August", 1962), 
            "Actor", ("Concord", "Massachusetts"))
for tup in t:
    for ele in tup:
        if year == str(ele):
            count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try the below code.

```
def get_count(t, year):
    count = 0

    for item in t:
        if type(item) is str:
            if year in item:
                count += 1
        elif type(item) is tuple:
                if int(year) in item or year in item:
                    count += 1
        elif type(item) is int:
            if int(year) == item:
                count += 1

    return count

# START
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # INPUT 1
    year = input("Enter a year")

    t = (("Steve"), ("Carell"), (16, "August", 1962),
                "Actor", ("Concord", "Massachusetts"))

    count = get_count(t, year)
    print(count)

    # INPUT 2
    year = input("Enter a year")

    t = (("Steve"), ("Carell", 1962), (16, "August", 1962),
                "Actor", ("Concord", "Massachusetts"))

    count = get_count(t, year)
    print(count) # 2

    # INPUT 3
    year = input("Enter a year")

    t = (("1962"), ("Carell", 1962), (16, "August", 1962),
                "Actor", ("Concord", "Massachusetts"), 1962)

    count = get_count(t, year)
    print(count) # 4
```

Answer (score 1):

What about solving it with one line code by using a list comprehension?

```
year = input ("enter a year")
t = (("Steve"), ("Carell"), (16, "August", 1962), 
    "Actor", ("Concord", "Massachusetts"))
print(len([j for k in t for j in k if j == year]))
```

Answer (score 0):

What if it is embedded deeply in another nest? It would be advisable to use regular expressions. You can use `re.search`:

```
import re

year = input ("enter a year: ")
count = 0 
t = (("Steve"), ("Carell"), (16, "August", 1962), 
            "Actor", ("Concord", "Massachusetts"))
if re.search(year,str(t)):
      count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score -1):

Would you mind trying this?

```
count = 0
year = 1962
tuples = (("Steve"), ("Carell"), (16, "August", 1962),
            "Actor", ("Concord", "Massachusetts"))

for tuple in tuples:
    if str(year) in str(tuple):
       count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: This might work, but comparing string membership in the string representation of a tuple is kind of awful.

Comment: At that point you may as well do `count = str(tuples).count(str(year))`